# Migration from Propel to Propel2

Tags: symfony, propel, symfony-2.7

I want to migrate a Symfony2 project (v.2.7.1) from Propel1.7 to Propel2 (currently "alpha 5").

I'm using various Propel behaviors and third party bundles which relies on "Propel" adaptators to correctly work. It will be very helpful for me to have your comments for each behavior / bundle to know if it's trivial to migrate or if difficulties (and which!) could happen...

**Behaviors:**

```
Archivable
NestedSet
Sluggable
QueryCache
Timestampable
Typehintable (willdurand/propel-typehintable-behavior)
Equalnest (craftyshadow/propel-equalnest-behavior)
Geocodable (willdurand/geocoder-bundle)
```

**Third party bundles:**

```
FOSUserBundle
GlorpenPropelBundle
FOSElasticaBundle
```

Answer (score 0):

**Core behaviors**

Theses behaviors are still in Propel2

Archivable
NestedSet
Sluggable
QueryCache
Timestampable

**Third-party behaviors**

```
Equalnest
```

The author does not seem confident in the compatibility like explained in this issue. I'll create a specific issue #969 to know the state of the art for managing an "equal nest" in Propel2.

```
Geocodable
```

A PR has been done here, but no news for a long time...
There is now a dedicated repo for Propel2.

**Core source**

The typehintable is in the core of Propel2, so it smells good

**Third-party bundles**

```
FOSUserBundle
```

Propel2 integration is related to that issue; as the typehintable behavior is now in the Propel core, I suppose we have to change the schema.xml supplied by default by FOSUserBundle for Propel.

```
GlorpenPropelBundle
```

It seems not compatible for the moment as explained here, but I suppose it would be better to discuss all the subjects covered in this fantastic bundle in a dedicated issue to know how Propel2 manage these problematics.

```
FosElasticaBundle
```

Even for Propel1, this bundle was a little bit hard to use, I suppose we have to work for Propel2.

Full links & discussion on github / https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/966